# Send jQuery $.data object through $.ajax GET

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form with a pile of input fields. I want to make a ajax GET request with all of the fields! Easiest way so far looks like assigning the inputs to a data object:

```
$('#myForm').find('input').each(function(index){ 
    myData = $.data($('#myForm'), $(this).attr('name'), $j(this).val());
});
```

...and then pump it through the ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url: '/otherpage.php',
    data = myData,
    error(function(){}),
    success(function(){});
});
```

But of course it doesn't work... no $_GET variables show up in the otherpage.php, and the console shows that `myData` is some huge object deal.

How do you send data through ajax like this? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the jQuery `serialize();` method:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url: '/otherpage.php',
    data = $('#myForm').serialize(),
    error(function(){}),
    success(function(){});
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: It's just that easy eh? Can't believe I didn't find that... thanks man :)

Comment: no probs, glad it helped! Mark the answer as accepted so others can find the solution if they have the same problem :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url: '/otherpage.php',
    data = $('#myForm').serialize(),
    error(function(){}),
    success(function(){});
});
```

Hope it'will help you.